# Use find to select attributes from joined tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables,

> QuestionSets
>
> - has_many :questions
>
> Question
>
> - has_many :answers
>
> Answers

Now the Answers table has a column called "actual_answer"

Now I wanted to do a find where I can get all the Answers with actual_answers equal to a specific value and belongs to a specific question_set.

I have this right now:

```
@questionSet= QuestionSet.find(params[:id])
@answers = Answer.find(:all, :conditions => ["actual_answer=?", SOMEACTUALANSWER])
answers_i_need = []
@answers.each do |answer|
  if answer.question.question_set_id == @questionSet.id
   answers_i_need << answer
  end
end
```

Is there a BETTER way of doing this, as I'm expecting thousand array results and making a loop might not be a perfect way of doing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `has_many ... :through` relation? Link to: [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

This way you can have:

```
QuestionSet
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions

Question
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :question_set

Answer
  belongs_to :question
```

Then in your controller you have:

```
@questionSet= QuestionSet.find(params[:id])
answers_i_need = @questionSet.answers.where('actual_answer = ?', your_actual_value)
```

Oh, and if you have more than a thousand results to query, you might consider having a look at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches).